# SPARQL subquery with limit

Tags: sparql, jena, semantic-web, fuseki

I'm using Apache Jena Fuseki to query my graph using SPARQL.

I need to do subquery with limit, and I found one example similar to my requirements [here](https://www.w3.org/2009/sparql/wiki/Design:SubSelect#Test_Cases).

The example looks like this.

#### Data

```
@prefix : <http://people.example/> .

:alice :name "Alice", "Alice Foo", "A. Foo" .
:alice :knows :bob, :carol . 
:bob :name "Bob", "Bob Bar", "B. Bar" .
:carol :name "Carol", "Carol Baz", "C. Baz" .
```

#### Query

```
PREFIX : <http://people.example/>
SELECT ?y ?name WHERE {
  :alice :knows ?y .
  {
    SELECT ?y ?name WHERE {
      ?y :name ?name
    }
    ORDER BY ?name
    LIMIT 1
  }
}
```

#### Result

```
?y          ?name
:bob        "B. Bar"
:carol      "C. Baz"
```

I did the same query with the same data on Fuseki, but the result is empty.

Is it problem of SPARQL implementation in Fuseki?

Which SPARQL engine can I use to get the same result as showed in the example?

Comment: Fuseki is correct. `ORDER BY` with no direction is always **ascending**. So, the subquery returns `:alice`, and obviously, according to your data, `:alice` does not know `:alice`, thus the result is empty

Comment: Note that your example is specifically referring to a design wiki that was used by the W3C working group in designing the sub-select feature.  The working group chose to maintain the pre-existing bottom up semantics of SPARQL evaluation in their specification of this feature so the specific example used as part of their design discussion does not work on compliant SPARQL implementations per @UninformedUser's comment